# Mobile phone interfering with WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking

I have been trying to solve the interferences problems I have when I use my laptop from a room that is not near to the Wifi repeater. The thing is that the Internet works fine randomly. Restarting the WiFi repeater and/or router used to work, but not always. Today I have realised that leaving my smartphone close to the laptop makes the Internet not work, but puting it on plane mode is letting me use the laptop with Internet without any problems.

Can my mobile phone be really be making my laptop unable to connect properly to the WiFi? Or this is only a symptom of something more?

Thank you.

Edit: my cellphone is an Acer Liquid E700, computer ASUS TP301UA, access point TP-LINK TL-WA801ND.

Comment: It would seem unlikely, but not impossible that this is the case.  Have you tried leaving your cellphone on but turning off WIFI?  Its possible that your phone is making your AP to negotiate a reduced signal strength due to their proximity.  Also, what kind of WIFI router and repeater do you have, and how many other AP's are visible?

Comment: @davidgo I have tested leaving my cellphone on but turning off WIFI. After additional testing, my conclusion is that it is the bluetooth which creates the interferences. The mobile phone on without bluetooth does not create any problem, regardless the wifi is on or off. It is strange, because the signal is not affected according to NetSpot, but I can check with an online ADSL speed test that, as soon as bluetooth is on, the connection breaks. Thank you for your clue!

Comment: Please update the question with make / model : Phone, laptop, router, repeater.  If there are other Bluetooth devices or even a poorly-shielded microwave, they can mess with it too.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Added that information inside the question.

Answer (score 2):

Some routers and wifi chipsets have a Bluetooth coexistence mode. (Depending on the make and model of the router, it would be in the web-ui).

Bluetooth and 2.4Ghz wifi use the same frequencies, because of this they will interfere.
This can also happen with the usb wireless keyboard & mice combos that run on 2.4Ghz  You can try adjusting the wifi channel in the router to either 1, 6, or 11. It can make a huge difference, Bluetooth was intended to be a PAN. It has much lower transmit power levels, this really shouldn't be an issue unless the Bluetooth device was within a couple feet of the router.

If you have a coexistence mode in the router use it.
If you do not, try choosing another wifi channel in the router configuration and see if it helps.

Another option would be to use a router with the 5.8Ghz band.